# How to run python in bash scripts on mac

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos

I have `python3` installed in my mac and I have `alias python='python3'` in my `.zshrc` file.

I have a bash script looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
python -c "print(123)"
```

But running the above script does not recognize `python`.  How can I let `bash` recognize `python` without changing the script file?

I added `alias python='python3'` to `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think aliases will apply in your script. Why not write `python3` directly?

Comment: Aliases don't automatically expand in shell scripts, you'd be better off using a function like `python() { python3 "${@}" ; }`. Also does bash even load the `.zshrc` file?

Comment: @khelwood I have too many scripts with `python` already.

Comment: Or alternatively you could create a symlink to your preferred python installation on your path and name the symlink `python`.

Comment: The .zshrc/.bashrc thing is because the script is in bash, but the caller is zsh on a mac. But that is symptomatic of the problem: aliases are the ones of the interactive shell, not of the script. Even if mac were using bash for interactive shell, those aliases would still be the aliases of the caller bash, not the called one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't.
Aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shell (that is in scripts).

If a slight modification of your script is acceptable, you could add

```bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias python=python3
```

on top of them.
(shopt -s expand_aliases change the "do no expand aliases since non-interactive" behavior. And then, you still need to create the alias)

Otherwise, if you really can't alter in any way your script, you could do as tjm suggested: create a python symlink someplace, and ensure that this place is sooner in the PATH than any other "python" that maybe in the PATH.

Just to demonstrate

```bash
mkdir /tmp/myextrabin
ln -s $(which python3) /tmp/myextrabin/python
PATH=/tmp/myextrabin:${PATH} ./script.sh
```

runs script.sh with python meaning whatever python3 means to the caller.